# Improve performance by excluding multiple conditions and List

Tags: c#, performance

This method works correctly and verifies whether a user has permissions to view or edit the first parameter (value). I think it is not the best implementation, because there are too many conditions and the `List` object isn't necessary. How to improve it?

```
protected override Exception GetValidationException( object value, string name )
{
  List<Entity> entities = value is int ? new List<Entity>( 1 ) { EntityCache.Entity.GetEntity( (int) value ) } :
                          value is Guid ? new List<Entity>( 1 ) { EntityCache.Entity.GetEntityByGuid( (Guid) value ) } :
                          value is int[] ? (value as int[]).Select( i => EntityCache.Entity.GetEntity( i ) ).ToList() :
                          value is Entity ? new List<Entity>( 1 ) { value as Entity } :
                          value is Entity[] ? (value as Entity[]).ToList() :
                          null;

  if( entities == null )
    throw new ArgumentException( string.Format( RI.UnknownArgumentType, name, value, value.GetType().Name ) );

  bool hasPermission = (from one in entities
                        select EntityPermissionCache.PermissionChecker( one.Id, one.EntityOrganizationId ) &&
                               _checkEditInsteadOfView ? EntityTypePermissionCache.PermissionChecker( true, one.TypeId ) : true)
                       .All( a => a );

  return hasPermission ? null : new AccessViolationException( RI.AccessDenied );
}
```

Comment: Unless you call this method very often, I really doubt its performance is going to be a problem. Have you profiled your code? Is this method really the part that's slowing it down? If not, this is a premature optimization.

Comment: Yes, it is a premature optimization. I have no way to test performance now, but this method calls everytime when users are trying to get any data from DB.

Comment: This is not a comment about performance.  Maybe you could rethink the design.  It does not seem very clean to me to have so many ways to call entities (int, int[], Entity,...).  If you do keep that many, maybe you could at least split your method into a first method to convert whatever to `List<Entity>` and then a second method to validate that list.

Comment: I agree. Splitting into different methods is good to understanding code.

Answer (score 2):

I think the assignment of your `entities` (bad name) is **uber-abusing** ternary expressions.

That said, my first thought was *why on Earth would you want to **return** an `Exception`*? So I googled up a bit and found [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/207232/are-there-legitimate-reasons-for-returning-exception-objects-instead-of-throwing):

> *Is it valid for a function to return exception objects?*
>
> Absolutely. Here is a short list of examples where this may be appropriate:
>
> - An exception factory.
> - A context object that reports if there was a previous error as a ready to use exception.
> - A function that keeps a previously caught exception.
> - A third-party API that creates an exception of an inner type.

Fine then. But there's a flaw in your API - you're taking in an `Object` for what seems to be an `Entity`.

If I understand what you're trying to do here, I believe you'd be better off with an overloaded method:

```
protected override Exception GetValidationException(int value, string name)
protected override Exception GetValidationException(Guid value, string name)
protected override Exception GetValidationException(int[] value, string name)
protected override Exception GetValidationException(Entity value, string name)
protected override Exception GetValidationException(Entity[] value, string name)
```

...Or I'd find a way to make something like this work:

```
protected override Exception GetValidationException<TValue>(TValue value, string name)
```